# Progress Bar Not Updating on button click

Tags: android, progress-bar

As and when i click to button, it waits for 20 seconds and then getting text to text view, my requirement is that after 1 second, progress bar has to increment by 5 values. 
Can any one guide me in following code

```
public class ProgressBar1 extends  Activity{

    TextView tvpbview;
    ProgressDialog pd1;
    ProgressBar pbhr1;
    Button btnhp1;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progressbar1);


        btnhp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgress);
        pbhr1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbHori1);
        pbhr1.setMax(100);


    btnhp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                //--- For Horizontal Progress Bar------

                for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
                {
                     pbhr1.incrementProgressBy(5);
                    tvpbview.setText(""+pbhr1.getProgress()+"% done");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);


                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should not do that on the main thread. AS it'll block the whole activity. That's the first idea you should have. Create a new Thread, and then send messages to a handler, and update the PB from there.

Answer (score 1):

You approach is incorrect, you need to use correct form of Threads. Especially for your case i recommend to you use following:

- [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Most likely you need to read some tutorial so have look at

- [`Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask -
  Tutorial`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

  this is a great source.

**Note:** `AsyncTask` is more complex than `Handler` and also is generic-type and is especially designed for updating `UI` with some progress.

Answer (score 0):

create an asynchronous task. Android provides the AsyncTask class for this purpose. You create a progress bar on the UI thread, then call the publishProgress() method to update your progress bar. It's really simple to use, the documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

try this

After they have been initially set, if you want to then change the values you need to set it to zero in between:

```
ProgressBar dataProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarData);

    //set to 0 first to stop the bug from happening

    dataProgressBar.setMax(0);
    dataProgressBar.setProgress(0);

    //set your new values

    dataProgressBar.setMax((int) dataAllowanceValue);
    dataProgressBar.setProgress((int) dataMBytes);
```